# Getting Fatal error when grails app comes up

Tags: java, xml, grails, xml-parsing

As soon as my grails as comes up, I start getting message below

> [Fatal Error] :28844:3: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
>   [Fatal Error] :43878:27: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

---

I am using following plugins for now:-

- compile(":shiro:1.2.1")
- compile ":restapidoc:0.1.1"
- runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.1"
- compile ":multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3"
- build(":release:3.0.1",
      ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
          export = false
      }
- compile ":quartz:1.0.2"

But issue doesn't seems to be with  these plugins. Neither I am manipulating any xml nor it seems grails is doing so.

Though everything is running well, I  am curious why such message is coming.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the error give any more context? What point in the process does the error appear? Can you try raising the logging level?  [grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#debuggingResolution](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#debuggingResolution)

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses some XML files behind the scenes. Make sure that everything looks good in the `web-app/WEB-INF` directory.

If those files all look good, then it might be one of the generated files. Try running `grails clean` and running again.

Comment: didn't find such files. tried grails clean and clean-all both.removed null folder that were created there by grails.Still getting same error